# Change keyboard layout boot2docker tinycore

Tags: linux, command-line, boot2docker

How can I change the keyboard layout of my boot2docker distribution (based on tinycore)?

/usr/share/kmap only contains the us.kmap

I found some solutions how to get kmaps.tcz but only with an X server and not just with the command line.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can change it from command line:

```
su docker
tce-load -wi kmaps
sudo loadkmap < /usr/share/kmap/azerty/fr-latin9.kmap
```

> Note: you need to do it from "docker" user since root is not able to perform `tce-load`

Comment: great. worked for me, on spanish keyboard: sudo loadkmap < /usr/share/kmap/qwerty/es.kmap

Comment: for german sudo loadkmap < /usr/share/qwertz/de-latin1.kmap worked for me

Comment: In case of (proxy problem, etc), the archive (_kmaps.tcz_) can be downloaded [there](http://repo.tinycorelinux.net/7.x/x86/tcz/kmaps.tcz) and unzipped.

Answer (score 3):

> for german sudo loadkmap < /usr/share/qwertz/de-latin1.kmap worked for me

sudo loadkmap < /usr/share/**kmap**/qwertz/de-latin1.kmap

worked for me

Answer (score 3):

**French keyboard:**

`su docker
 tce-load -wi kmaps
 sudo loadkmap < /usr/share/kmap/azerty/fr-latin9.kmap`

**Spanish keyboard:**

`su docker
 tce-load -wi kmaps
 sudo loadkmap < /usr/share/kmap/qwerty/es.kmap`

**German keyboard:**

`su docker
 tce-load -wi kmaps
 sudo loadkmap < /usr/share/kmap/qwertz/de-latin1.kmap`